# Unmarshall xml to list of objects

Tags: jaxb, jersey

My rest jersey service returns a list of Customers, in this case there is only one.

```
<customers>
 <customer>
  <age>24</age>
  <id>163</id>
  <name>Lory</name>
  <surname>Vinci</surname>
  <docNumber>123</docNumber>
  <fiscalCode>12345bg</fiscalCode>
 </customer>
</customers>
```

now I'd like to get a list of Customer, but in this example I get only one Customer

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;



public class ClientTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RONF/rest/customers");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(output);
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        System.out.println(customer.getName());

      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

}
}
```

The classes are like that:
User has 4 attributes: name, surname, id, age
Customer extends User with 2 further attributes which are docNumber and fiscalCode.
I also get this exception generated by

```
Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

and it's:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"customers"). Expected elements are <{}customer>,<{}user>
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:243)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:238)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1048)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:483)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:465)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:135)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3065)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:881)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:203)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:175)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
at ClientTest.main(ClientTest.java:37)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Customers` class that holds a `List` of `Customer` objects and add that to your model.

```java
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customers {
    @XmlElement(name="customer")
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

For a more generic approach check out my answer to a related question:

- [How to marshalling the muliptle object using jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323397/how-to-marshalling-the-muliptle-object-using-jaxb/12323657#12323657)