# JAXBContext newInstance(class,class) explanation

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to understand JAXB and looking to initialize multiple objects using JAXB.  I found an excellent question asked and answered in StackOverFlow.

[How to marshalling the muliptle object using jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323397/how-to-marshalling-the-muliptle-object-using-jaxb)

So I'm looking through the code, trying to understand each piece.  The first and key part (I think) that I'm having trouble understanding is the following line:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXB2_Lists.class, JAXB2_Book.class);
```

Looking through the JAXBContext documentation, I'm unable to determine which newInstance method is being used.  Guessing which one is being used, I'm not understanding it really.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class...)

My guess is that it is using the following overload

```
public static JAXBContext newInstance(Class[] classesToBeBound,
                                      Map<String,?> properties)
                               throws JAXBException
```

> Parameters:
>
> classesToBeBound - list of java classes to be recognized by the new
>   JAXBContext.

What does it mean by "to be recognized"?  Recognized in what way?

Please educate me on this issue.  Thank you.

Comment: Recognized in the way that those objects are meant to be marshalled and unmarshalled by JAXB, so JAXB must be taught about which classes they are, so that it recognizes them as valid JAXB targets (and scans the relevant annotations they contain) .

Comment: Thanks Berger, but it is the Book class that is being marshaled in the coded example, correct?  The code has the List class first, so is it marshalling both the List and Book classes?

Comment: Yes, in the example from your link, a List is marshalled, which contains Book objects (so Books are also marshalled "in cascade"), so both have to be "recognized" by JAXB .

Comment: Why aren't you providing these answers as an answer, so I can give you thumbs up? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Recognized* in the way that those objects are meant to be marshalled and unmarshalled by JAXB, so JAXB must be taught about which classes they are, so that it recognizes them as valid JAXB targets (and scans/processes the relevant annotations they contain) .

In the example from your link, a `List` is marshalled, which contains `Book` objects (so Books are also marshalled "in cascade"), so both have to be "recognized"/"known" by JAXB .

Furthermore, the method you are actually calling is :

[public static JAXBContext newInstance(Class... classesToBeBound)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class...))

From the description :

> Not only the new context will recognize all the classes specified, but
>   it will also recognize any classes that are directly/indirectly
>   referenced statically from the specified classes.

Because your `List` references `Book`, I guess you can omit the `Book`class from the parameters, and simply call

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXB2_Lists.class);
```

Comment: Did I identify the correct overload method?  So for the Class[] classesToBeBound, one can provide a list of Class objects?  So how does the "Map<String,?> properties" parameter get involved?  That isn't explained at all, as I'm able to determine from the documentation I provided.

Thanks for your help. =)

Comment: You are not calling this method, I updated the answer to bring more details.

Comment: I have one small doubt with regards to `JAXB new instance`. I need to `unmarshal` the classes which are present in the different `maven submodule`. I know now how to pass the `package` name when in the same `maven module or project` but if the classes are present in different `submodules` then how can I pass the `package` name? Do I need to pass the `package` name along with the `submodule` information? if so then can you provide me an example? I tried a. lot of things and searched many answers but could not find anything.