# JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context while marshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, jaxb2

I am getting below error while marshalling. I generated xml's from schemas.

```
[javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class org.com.AccountsComplexType nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

After a little research, some people says "Try adding @XmlSeeAlso(...class)" but the problem is AccountsComplexType class is not a XmlRootElement.

Is there any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237473/jaxb-exception-class-not-known-to-this-context)

Answer (score 1):

If you generated the classes form an XML schema then you should bootstrap the `JAXBContext` from the package name of the generated model or the `ObjectFactory` class.

Comment: I created object with AccountsComplexType act = new ObjectFactory().createAccountsComplexType(); but error still continues.