# Spring MVC XML view

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have been following a tutorial [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-xml-example/)

As it stands, it works fine.

But if I try to convert a class hierarchy to XML, I get exceptions

Example:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "stuff")
public class Stuff {

    @XmlMixed
    public List<Other> getList(){
      return records;
    }

}
```

Other class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="other")
public class Other {
  @XmlAttribute int foo;
}
```

And the important part of the exception:

```
class mypackage.Other nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a quick workaround:

Add :

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Other.class) to Stuff .
```

You should check the following posts for more insights

[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Class *** nor any of its super class is known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057932/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-class-nor-any-of-its-super-class-is-known-to-t)

[JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237473/jaxb-exception-class-not-known-to-this-context)