# Spring HATEOAS (w Spring Boot) JAXB marshal error when returning a Resources<T> or PagedResources<T> result

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I've got something like this in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<PromotionResource>> promotions(
        @PageableDefault(size = RestAPIConfig.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE, page = 0) Pageable pageable,
        PagedResourcesAssembler<Promotion> assembler
){

    PagedResources<PromotionResource> r = assembler.toResource(this.promoService.find(pageable), this.promoAssembler);

    return new ResponseEntity<PagedResources<PromotionResource>>(r, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If i navigate to the URL mapped to that controller method i get a 500 error with a root cause of:

```
com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "commerce.api.rest.resources.PromotionResource " as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

If i throw a @XmlRootElement annotation on my resource it becomes this error:

```
com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "commerce.api.rest.resources.PromotionResource " as an element because it is not known to this context.
```

Everything is fine if the accept header is application/json or application/hal+json.  The problem is caused only when the client (in this case chrome) is looking for application/xml (which makes sense as HATEOAS is following the clients requests.  I'm using spring boot's @EnableAutoConfiguration which is adding the XML message converter to the list and thus enabling XML content types.

I'm guessing i have at least 2 options:
1. fix the jaxb error
2. remove xml as a supported content type

not sure how to do either, or maybe there's another option.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237473/jaxb-exception-class-not-known-to-this-context).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't actually want to produce XML try using the `produces` attribute of the `@RequestMapping` annotation. Something like: `@RequestMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Alternatively you could exclude `jaxb` from you classpath or look at adding your own `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters` bean to take complete control of the registered `HttpMessageConverter`'s. See `WebMvcConfigurationSupport.addDefaultHttpMessageConverters` to see what Spring will add by default.

Comment: i do not want to have to annotate all my actions with that

Comment: any change you can be more specific in your answer...i'm trying stuff but there is nightmare chain of message converters going on here...all i want to do is disable 1 specific converter without having to rewrite the world

Comment: OK, it turns out it is actually quite a pain to remove items from HttpMessageConverters with the 1.1.5 release. I've addressed this for 1.1.6 (should be released this week). See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1482 and the test case https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/34cbcf5e5061fc9e5accb9ea4dd6e5bb64e68b02/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpMessageConvertersTests.java#L102-L126

Comment: that is easier, check my answer to how i ended up getting it working, although i wasn't confident it was a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a good technique, and it looks like in 1.1.6 there's a different approach.  Here's what i did:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        //Remove the Jaxb2 that is automatically added because some other dependency brings it into the classpath
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> baseConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        super.configureMessageConverters(baseConverters);

        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> c : baseConverters){
            if(!(c instanceof Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter)){
                converters.add(c);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to support XML converter, you can extend spring WebMvcConfigurer to exclude XML message converters.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.removeIf(c -> c instanceof AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter<?>);
    }

}
```

Comment: sure today you can do it this easily...but only because of this question which prompted this enhancement   see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480517/spring-hateoas-w-spring-boot-jaxb-marshal-error-when-returning-a-resourcest/56643017#comment40016230_23489883