# CXF WebService Call from Grails

Tags: web-services, grails, jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to call a WebService from Grails using CXF plugin version: 1.1.3

Have generated Java classes for the WSDL via the command:

```
WsdlToJava "--wsdl=src/java/wsdls/jdeRteListenerService.wsdl --mark -p mypackage.pms.OsrJdeRteSvc -client -impl"
```

When I went to run the webservice call I would get:

> Class not known to this context for class: mypackage.pms.OsrJdeRteSvc.ListAllEventsRequest.

Following this stackoverflow article: [JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237473/jaxb-exception-class-not-known-to-this-context)

I added to the Port class:

@XmlSeeAlso({mypackage.pms.OsrJdeRteSvc.impl.ObjectFactory.class, mypackage.pms.OsrJdeRteSvc.ListAllEventsRequest.class})

Now I get the error:

> Unable to find a JAXB implementation to delegate.

JAXB Source has a comment:

```
if(!modified) {
            // if the class list doesn't contain any of our classes,
            // this ContextFactory shouldn't have been called in the first place
            // if we simply continue, we'll just end up with the infinite recursion.

            // the only case that I can think of where this could happen is
            // when the user puts additional classes into the JAXB-generated
            // package and pass them to JAXBContext.newInstance().
            // Under normal use, this shouldn't happen.

            // anyway, bail out now.
            // if you hit this problem and wondering how to get around the problem,
            // subscribe and send a note to users@jaxb.dev.java.net (http://jaxb.dev.java.net/)
            throw new JAXBException("Unable to find a JAXB implementation to delegate");
        }
```

https://svn.java.net/svn/jaxb~version2/tags/jaxb-2_2_3u1/xjc/src/com/sun/tools/xjc/runtime/JAXBContextFactory.java

I've subscribed to the list but not yet been approved.

Anyway, why am I getting: Unable to find JAXB implementation to delegate?

Comment: JAXB guys suggest problem is in my JAXBContextFactory. This was generated with wsdl2java. Will try without impls

Comment: Running without -impl flag still seems to generate impls