# JAXBException occurred : unable to marshal type "mypackage.myclass."as an element because it is not known to this context

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, soapui

For an REST api I have create a class with @XMLRootElement annotation , and when providing the request in SOAPUi , getting below error .

```
JAXBException occurred : unable to marshal type "mypackage.myclass."as an element because it is not known to this context..
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: That depends on a lot of the code you didn't include in your post. [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB Exception: Class not known to this context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237473/jaxb-exception-class-not-known-to-this-context)